# c++ Send the string to a function to determine how long is the string

Tags: c++, function, c-strings

I know how to use a string to calculate the number of characters, but I'm not sure how to use a function to do that. have to use CSTRING. THANK YOU ALL

```
#include <cstring>
char a[10];

cout << "Please enter anything: ";
cin.getline(a,10);

cout << "You type " << strlen(a) << " letters long"<<endl;
```

Comment: Simple: use `std::string` and `std::string::size`. That's all you need.

Comment: *Send the string to a function to determine how long is the string* -- Isn't that what you're doing when you call `strlen(a)`?  Exactly what issue are you having?  And why resort to character arrays when you have `std::string`, and can just use `std::string mystring; std::getline(cin, mystring);` call `mystring.size()` and forget about null-terminated strings?

Comment: With `strlen(a)` you did exactly that. If you need to write a function to do the counting, loop through the characters in the string and increment the count until you find the string's terminator. Then return the count.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for std::string since you're question mentioned C++ and not only C.

```
include <string>

std::string myString = "Something";
size_t stringLength = myString.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just type your code inside a function()

```
int stringlengthfunction()
 {
char str[80];

int i;

cout<<"\n enter string:";

cin.getline(str,80);

int n=strlen(str);

cout<<"\n lenght is:"<<n;

getch();

return 0;

}
```

or pass your string as a parameter to the function

```
int stringlengthfunction(string str)
```